# What is wrong with my project hierarchy?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have created a project by importing existing sources in Intellij IDEA.

[image]

When I run from my comand line,sbt and then console I got this

```
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources to 

/home/milenko/example/project/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/milenko/example/project/CommonBuild.scala:20: not found: type ModuleID
[error]                       dependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(),
[error]                                         ^
[error] /home/milenko/example/project/CommonBuild.scala:26: not found: type Build
[error] trait CommonBuild extends Build {
[error]                           ^
[error] /home/milenko/example/project/CommonBuild.scala:28: not found: value SettingKey
[error]   val course = SettingKey[String]("course")
[error]                ^
[error] /home/milenko/example/project/CommonBuild.scala:30: not found: value SettingKey
[error]   val assignment = SettingKey[String]("assignment")
[error]                    ^
[error] /home/milenko/example/project/CommonBuild.scala:32: not found: value SettingKey
[error]   val assignmentsMap = SettingKey[Map[String, Assignment]]("assignmentsMap")
```

My example folder

```
milenko@milenko-desktop:~/example$ ls
assignment.sbt  build.sbt  project  src  target
```

Then I have changed directory to project,and run `sbt` and `console` in project.

My IDEA import is here

[image]

It seems that CommonBuild.scala is not positioned at the wright place.How to change this?

Comment: But did it work in SBT console before you've imported the project into Intellij?

Comment: @Haspemulator I do not know,I am learning from coursera tutorial,following step by step.They told us to import the data.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong here, but I assume it has something to do with paths: which exactly path you've imported into Intellij and where you run the SBT console. Please provide this info in the question.

Comment: @Haspemulator Take a look at my edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `sbt` command from the root of your build, not in the `project` directory. `project` directory is used to build the build definition of your project, because [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive).

In other words, in your case you need to run `sbt` in `~/example` directory.

Comment: Works perfect now.